# Resgatar valores de um XML contido em uma String

Tags: java

Tenho uma String, que contem um XML com uma estrutura parecida a esta:

```
<TAG0>
   <TAG1>
      <TAG2>valor1</TAG2>
   </TAG1>
   <TAG1>
      <TAG2>valor2</TAG2>
   </TAG1>
</TAG0>
```

No caso eu tenho Tags com o mesmo nome, que se repetem no corpo do XML, como uma venda, que contem vários itens. A String com o XML esta com o texto corrido sem espaços. Ex.:

```
String VARIAVEL = "<TAG0><TAG1><TAG2>valor1</TAG2></TAG1><TAG1><TAG2>valor2</TAG2></TAG1></TAG0>"
```

O que tenho que fazer, como segue nesse exemplo, é resgatar os valores das tags "TAG2", sabendo que posso ter N tags como "TAG1". O caso real é resgatar todas os CFOPs dos itens de uma NFe.

Comment: Veja se este link lhe ajuda em algo: http://www.guj.com.br/java/169353-ler-conteudo-xml-contido-em-uma-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É possível pegar os valores com regex, mas há a desvantagem de precisar alterá-lo sempre que precisar procurar por outro elemento. Eu sugiro que você crie um [**`Document`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Document.html), assim fica mais simples pegar os elementos pelo nome.

Alterei o nome das tags para o código ficar mais sucinto, mas a estrutura continua a mesma e a ideia é pegar o texto nos elementos **`<c>`**:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<a>
  <b>
     <c>Valor 1</c>
  </b>
  <b>
     <c>Valor 2</c>
  </b>
</a>
```

Segue uma solução utilizando essas classes do próprio Java:

```
import java.io.StringReader;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
```

E o código para *parsear* a string em XML e obter o conteúdo dos elementos:

```
String xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><a><b><c>valor 1</c></b><b><c>valor 2</c></b></a>";

DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

Document xmlDocument = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));

// Pega os elementos em que o nome da tag seja "c":
NodeList nodes = xmlDocument.getElementsByTagName("c");
for(int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++)
    System.out.println(nodes.item(i).getTextContent());
```

#### output:

> Valor 1 
>   Valor 2

Answer (score 0):

Você pode resolver o problema utilizando expressões regulares. Se você tem o texto bem definido no formato que mostrou o código abaixo vai resolver.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String texto = "<TAG0><TAG1><TAG2>valor1 x</TAG2>" + 
                      "</TAG1><TAG1><TAG2>valor2</TAG2></TAG1></TAG0>";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<tag2>(.+?)</tag2>", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(texto);
    while( m.find() ){
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
}
```

Eu quebrei a string apenas para ficar melhor apresentável aqui.

O que o código está fazendo é identificando o padrão que você solicitou através de uma expressão regular `<tag2>(.+?)</tag2>` que significa:

Encontre o texto `<tag2>` seguido de qualquer coisa de forma não gulosa, seguido do texto `</tag2>` utilizando o parâmetro `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE` para ignorar maiúsculas e minúsculas.

`while( m.find() )` percorre o texto enquanto existir o mesmo padrão e `m.group(1)` para imprimir o agrupamento 1 definido no padrão pelos parênteses,  no caso `(.+?)`

Para visualizar a regex funcionando, veja aqui:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O link da ferramenta que usei com o padrão criado: https://www.debuggex.com/r/3aqFTNWTTpkHkPCe