# WebService Correios - Rastreamento

Tags: java

Estou tentando consumir o Web service dos Correios - Rastreamento.
No net Benas importei o WSDL em novo->cliente para Webservice.
O problema é que o WebService está retornando a lista de  vazia, não estou conseguindo entender.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Sroxml result = buscaEventos("ECT", "SRO", "L", "T", "101", "OC013972795BR");
    System.out.println("qtd "+result.getQtd());
    System.out.println("Objeto "+result.getObjeto());
    System.out.println(result.getObjeto().get(0).getNumero());
    System.out.println(result.getObjeto().get(0).getEvento().get(0).getDescricao());
}

private static Sroxml buscaEventos(java.lang.String usuario, java.lang.String senha, java.lang.String tipo, java.lang.String resultado, java.lang.String lingua, java.lang.String objetos) {
    br.com.correios.webservice.resource.Rastro service = new br.com.correios.webservice.resource.Rastro();
    br.com.correios.webservice.resource.Service port = service.getServicePort();
    return port.buscaEventos(usuario, senha, tipo, resultado, lingua, objetos);
}
```

}

E está dando este erro:

> run: qtd 1
>
> Objeto []
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index:
>   0, Size: 0    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)   at
>   java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)   at
>   javaapplication3.JavaApplication3.main(JavaApplication3.java:11)
>   C:\Users\lorena\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication3\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1041:
>   The following error occurred while executing this line:
>   C:\Users\lorena\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication3\nbproject\build-impl.xml:806:
>   Java returned: 1 FALHA NA CONSTRUÇÃO (tempo total: 5 segundos)

Comment: Estou implementando a mesma coisa, se quiser posto meu código de como eu busco as informações.

Comment: Douglas, ficaria muito agradecido se você postasse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estou implementando o mesmo caso e você pode usar este exemplo que trabalha perfeitamente: Observe apenas que o código chega como parâmetro e no final eu trato o `xml`. Você pode ficar a vontade para fazer suas modificações:

```
public static String consultarCodigo(String codigo) throws IOException, SOAPException{

            String xml = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:res=\"http://resource.webservice.correios.com.br/\">"
                    + "   <soapenv:Header/>" + "   <soapenv:Body>" + "      <res:buscaEventos>"
                    + "         <usuario>ECT</usuario>" + "         <senha>SRO</senha>" + "         <tipo>L</tipo>"
                    + "         <resultado>T</resultado>" + "         <lingua>101</lingua>"
                    + "         <objetos>"+codigo+"</objetos>" + "      </res:buscaEventos>" + "   </soapenv:Body>"
                    + "</soapenv:Envelope>";
            SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
            SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();
            // URL do Webservice
            String url = "http://webservice.correios.com.br:80/service/rastro";
            MimeHeaders headers = new MimeHeaders();
            headers.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");

            MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();

            SOAPMessage msg = messageFactory.createMessage(headers, (new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes())));

            SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(msg, url);
            Document xmlRespostaARequisicao = soapResponse.getSOAPBody().getOwnerDocument();
            return passarXMLParaString(xmlRespostaARequisicao, 4);
        }

        public static String passarXMLParaString(Document xml, int espacosIdentacao) {
            try {
                // set up a transformer
                TransformerFactory transfac = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
                transfac.setAttribute("indent-number", new Integer(espacosIdentacao));
                Transformer trans = transfac.newTransformer();
                trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
                trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");

                // create string from xml tree
                StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                StreamResult result = new StreamResult(sw);
                DOMSource source = new DOMSource(xml);
                trans.transform(source, result);
                String xmlString = sw.toString();
                return xmlString.substring(xmlString.indexOf("<objeto>"), xmlString.indexOf("</objeto>")+10);
            } catch (TransformerException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(0);
            }
            return null;
```

Comment: Douglas, e como você acessa os índices? por exemplo para salvar no banco de dados, quero salvar apenas o ultimo status do objeto, como eu atribuo este evento a uma variável?

Comment: <objeto>
                    <numero>OC013972795BR</numero>
                    <sigla>OC</sigla>
                    <nome>ENCOMENDA E-SEDEX (ETIQ LOGICA)</nome>
                    <categoria>E-SEDEX</categoria>
                    <evento>
                        <tipo>BDE</tipo>
                        <status>01</status>
                        <data>22/03/2017</data>
                        <hora>14:26</hora>
                        <descricao>Objeto entregue ao destinatário</descricao>

Comment: Eu estou usando uma tecnologia chamada `JAXB`, ele meio que pega os valores entre tags e popula um atributo do objeto.

Comment: Vou testar......

Comment: Douglas, para acessar os valores da String XMl de retorno, achei muito bom este metodo também: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/92363/resgatar-valores-de-um-xml-contido-em-uma-string